# Wordpress single.php inside a bootstrap modal? Please tell me if this is a waste of time

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'order'=> 'DESC',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'attachment'
    );

$get_children_array = get_children($args,ARRAY_A);  //returns Array ( [$image_ID]... 
$rekeyed_array = array_values($get_children_array);
$child_image = $rekeyed_array[0];


        ?>


<article class="col-sm-3 blurb-box" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $child_image[guid];?>');">
    <div class="title-text">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>     
    </div>
    <button 
            type="button" 

            href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" 

            class="btn btn-success btn-md" 
            data-toggle="modal" 
            data-target="#myModal">
            Open Modal
    </button>

</article> 

<?php endwhile; else : ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

This works on first click. After refresh and gives you a single.php with the appropriate content in  modal. Other clicks without refresh continue to produce the the same modal for which ever post you clicked on first.

Any thoughts? Should I forget about this?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are trying to map one modal window to multiple "Open Modal" buttons. Because your "data-target" attribute will always have the same value in the loop.

A good way is to use ajax for getting the content of modal window i.e single post content. A quick googling can set you up in no time.